# Break one loop based on the condition of another - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, multiprocessing, conditional-statements

I'm writing a script to receive data over a serial communication line from an MCU connected to a pressure sensor.

The idea is that I would continuously poll the MCU for pressure information in one loop and gather data in another. I would like to be able to stop the data collection once the pressure is no longer constant.

There are two `while` loops, one that polls the MCU and one that gathers data, but I need them to run concurrently so that the polling loop can provide the condition to the collection loop to stop.

```
#Loop that polls MCU
def poll(serial_data):
  data = serial_data
  while data_in:
      _, pressure = Get_data(data, 2000)
      difference = np.diff(pressure[:,1])

      if (all(i<1000 for i in difference) and all(i>-1000 for i in difference)):
          print('Pressure constant. Start collecting.')
          return True
      else:
          print('Pressure is not constant.') #break 2nd loop on this condition
          return False

def some_other_function(serial_data):
  input = ""
  data = serial_data
  #Loop to continously gather data
  while (poll(data) == True): # I realise this line probably isn't correct
     input_bytes = serial_data.read()
     input_string = str(input_bytes,'utf-8')
     input += input_string

  # Want to break 1st loop now that data collection has stopped
```

I have been looking into multi-processing for doing this but am unsure of how to implement it so that one loop will depend on the other.

Comment: Why can't you just put it into one loop in `Some_other_function`? And don't use upper case naming for functions.

Comment: Some questions: in `Poll` you have a parameter `data`, loop over `data_in` and again use `data`. I think that's a mistake? In `Some_other_function` you again get `data` as a parameter, but you call `Poll` without any parameters - that won't work, as `Poll` needs an argument. Perhaps you wanted to give `data` as parameter to `Poll`? Or maybe `input_bytes`?

Comment: @Igle I haven't got them in the same loop in some_other_function because the Get_data function that is called involves taking a user specified number of points and checking them. The method for doing this is similar to what you see in some_other function. As far as I'm aware doing this would mean collecting data, stopping to check if the pressure is constant and repeating. I need to be collecting data continuously as I want to avoid missing valuable information.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Thank you for your questions. I've updated my code to hopefully help with the understanding.

Comment: So if I understand correctly from what you wrote to Igle, you want `poll` to run continuously, some pause in there for the time `some_other_function` needs to process one iteration of the body of the while loop is not wanted?

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle I'd like poll to run continuously, you are correct. But once the pressure is constant i.e. when `poll` returns `True`, I'd like `some_other_function` to start and keep running until `poll` returns `False`. So both functions will at one point need to be running at the same time.

Comment: That is kind of hard to implement with just synchronous programming. You are better off using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) if you want both loops to run simultaneously.

Comment: @RottenCandy Thank you, I'm having a look at multiprocessing now. It's not something I've ever really come across before so it'll take some learning on my part! And I have no idea how my two processes can be dependent on each other. I'm assuming it'll be something to do with a `send` and `receive`?